# Restrict access or redirect devise path users/sign_in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am creating a rails app. And i have login in such a way that, users are directed or redirect to /login for signing in. And when users/sign_in is passed the it embeds the sign in form into the application layout which i don't want users to see. Is there a way i can redirect users/sign_in to /login or restrict access to it ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this. It should works. ;)

```rb
config/routes.rb

# change :devise_model to :user, or :admin or any name of your devise model 
devise_scope :devise_model do
    get '/login' => "devise/sessions#new"
end
```

and you can use this in view like this.

```
link_to 'Login', login_url
```

**PS. if you have override devise controller. You should tell the router first, and change devise controller to your override controller name.**

[go to this link](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) and see ***Configuring controllers*** content.

Comment: there is no error message. It just stays there. i have a controller login with index method. Which had a sign in form... which i am using at /login. now i want /users/sign_in to redirect to /login. but that doesnt work

Comment: okay, I have see @clemensp answer and I recommend you follow his answer. 
But your last comment that say your code is...
`devise_for :user, :path => '', :path_names => {:sign_in => 'login'}`

you miss the s letter in model_name change it to
`devise_for :users, ..........`

it should works ;)

Comment: I try that stupid me.
It works fine but, it just look at different views locate. :(

Answer (score 1):

The following will replace the routes:

```
devise_for :model_name, :path => '', 
  :path_names => {:sign_in => 'login', :sign_out => 'logout'}
```

It will replace the users/sign_in and users/sign_out routes with login/logout, and the redirects will take them to those routes accordingly as well.

Comment: it didnt .. this what i entered my routes.rb file

devise_for :user, :path => '', 
  :path_names => {:sign_in => 'login'}

Comment: Hmm, weird... I currently have an app set up with that, and when I go to /users/sign_in, it says the route doesn't exist, and if I go to /login, it works.

Comment: can you post the example plz? may be i passed some value wrong ?

Comment: This is exactly what I'm using:   devise_for :users, :path_names => {:sign_in => "login", :sign_out => "logout"}, :path => ""